# How to create segmented plot that uses data in dataframe in sequential order?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> print(df)
  person step start end
1    sam    A     0   4
2    sam    B     4   6
3   greg    A     2   7
4   greg    B     7  11
```

And I created the following plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(colour=step)) + 
 geom_segment(aes(x=start, xend=end, y=person, yend=person), size=3) +
  xlab("Duration")
```

[image: Segmented Plot]

This looks exactly as I want it to be. However, my input data structure has changed to the following:

```
 step       sam    greg
1    A        0       2
2    B        4       7
3    C        6      11
```

This structure has basically the same meaning, but I don't know how I can easily convert it so that `geom_segment` understands that it is now column-wise and not per row. Do I need to transform it back to the old data structure (with start and end) or can I somehow workaround that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually not a `ggplot2` question, but a data wrangling question with the goal to create your first data frame based on your second data frame. Here is an option with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  gather(person, Value, -step) %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  slice(rep(row_number(), each = 2)) %>%
  slice(2:(n() - 1)) %>%
  mutate(Type = rep(c( "start", "end"), times = n()/2),
         step = rep(LETTERS[1:(n()/2)], each = 2)) %>%
  spread(Type, Value) %>%
  arrange(person, step) %>%
  select(step, person, start, end) %>%
  arrange(desc(person), step) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#   step  person start   end
#   <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
# 1 A     sam        0     4
# 2 B     sam        4     6
# 3 A     greg       2     7
# 4 B     greg       7    11
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = " step       sam    greg
1    A        0       2
                  2    B        4       7
                  3    C        6      11",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! Excellent answer.